# Call qooxdoo rpc from Angular 2 (Typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, external, rpc, qooxdoo

my problem is that I have 2 projects. One with qooxdoo and one with Angular 2. Is it possible to call the qooxdoo rpc from Angular 2.
Or is it possible to use parts of qooxdoo in angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qooxdoo's RPC client is a standard-compliant JSON-RPC client conforming to the specification at http://www.jsonrpc.org. (Well, it's compliant, but not quite full-featured, in that it isn't currently able to send batch requests.) If you have a JSON-RPC server with which you are already communicating from your qooxdoo JSON-RPC client, you should be able to find a JSON-RPC standard-compliant client designed for Angular 2 which can also talk to that same server.

Derrell